# Adding a button that looks like a link in Bootstrap3's navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Adding

```
<li><input class="btn btn-link" type="submit" value="Log out"></li>
```

to the navbar shows a link, but it has an underline on hover and also is much higher than the other links:

[image]

(Hovering cursor turned invisible during screenshotting process.)

I can play with styles, but I wondered if there's an official way to make it behave like a normal navbar link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-links) it's supposed to be..

```
<p class="navbar-text"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">Link</a></p>
```

So you could use your input button instead like this:

```
<p class="navbar-text"><input type="button" class="btn-link" value="Link"></p>
```

Example: http://bootply.com/wfMQu1hytI